# MySQL BIGINT conversion to Java Long

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, casting, bigint

Why a MYSQL column of type `bigint` cannot be casted to Java Long?

When using `JPA.em().createNativeQuery("select ...").getResultList()` and the select result is a column from the type `bigint`, you can't assign the result to a `Long` variable.

The cast causes a run time exception

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.lang.Long

This of course can be solved by using a `BigInteger` variable and then `.longValue()`

I'm trying to understand what is the underlying reason for this error.

Both of them, `Long` and `bigint`, are signed 8 byte.

(for mySql: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/integer-types.html)

(for java: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

According to different sources, `Long` is the equivalent java datatype for MYSQL `bigint`.
(http://openwritings.net/content/public/java/mapping-java-and-mysql-data-types),

what distinguishes one from the other and makes the cast impossible?

Using Java 7 and MySql 5.5.57

Comment: The MySQL JDBC driver returns a BigInteger. A BigInteger is not a Long. So you can't cast. According to MySQL documentation (table 5.2 in https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-type-conversions.html), it should return a Long for a signed BIGINT. If it returns a BigInteger, it's proably that your BIGINT is in fact unsigned.

Comment: The type is: bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT

Comment: Made some tests with MySQL Connector/J 5.1.46. Not null BIGINT is mapped to long, nullable  BIGINT  is mapped to BIgInteger, no matter if it is unisgned or not. This behaviour doesn't match what is written in the documentation.